# Привязана ли переменная окружения, созданная с помощью setenv() к процессу, в котором она была создана?

Tags: c, unix

Создаю дочерний процесс с помощью fork(), в дочернем процессе объявляю переменную окружения с помощью setenv().

Эта переменная будет недоступна везде кроме процесса, в котором она была создана, или она становится глобальной ?

Comment: Эта переменная (точнее - ее копия) будет доступна во всех дочерних процессах, но не будет доступна во всех родительских процессах

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все переменные среды являются локальными для процесса, в котором они устанавливаются.

Также копии среды передаются потомкам при вызове `fork()`.